# PHP, MySQL. Min and max value day, month and year

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, max, min

Edit for clarification:

This is my table:

```
ID      Datetime            Date        Temp
6043    2016-05-24 10:20:00 2016-05-24  19.3
6042    2016-05-24 10:15:00 2016-05-24  19.1
6041    2016-05-24 10:10:00 2016-05-24  19.1
6040    2016-05-24 10:05:00 2016-05-24  19.1
```

What I'm trying to do is to select the row with the highest "Temp".

This is my query:

```
SELECT max(temp) as maxtemp FROM weatherdata WHERE day(date) = 24
```

The query only gives me the maxtemp, how can I get the ID and Datetime?

Goal is to get the max-value for each day in my table (WHERE day(date) = xx)

Kind Regards

Comment: _"But it's not working"_ means what? What is the output? What do you expect to be the output? Do you get an error?

Comment: I would expect that you only get a result _IF_ that specific day is the hottest in your database. That's what you're searching for.

Comment: Hi Jeff thanks for your comment. I dont get any output in the browser and also no error since my admin turned that off. Hmm ok to your second comment, then, how can I get the max and min values?

Comment: In simple text: I "just" want to get the max and min values from the year, month and day. Maybe my first steps are the wrong way to start?

Comment: Do you want to get the max date in corresponding years? What if the max date is in another year. Then your query will return null. You really need to show the table on which the query is working.

Comment: Hmm true about the year :/ This is (part of) my table: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=30rp83s&s=9#.V0BQNOQv0hI

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify it, and please don't use links to third-party sites to show key parts of your question. The link in your comment  shows me ads but nothing useful.

Comment: Clarification is in my comments. I see that my posted code is not the way to go but I dont know what else to do :/

Comment: Cut and paste the text of the sample of your table into your question. Indent it four spaces. Don't clarify your question in your comments, [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to get your entire `weatherdata` observation row for the observation that contains the highest temperature in any given month.

This takes two steps, as you have realized.  The first step: find the highest temperature observation in each month.  You do that like so:

```
              SELECT MAX(temp) temp, LAST_DAY(`datetime`) month_ending
                FROM weatherdata
               GROUP BY LAST_DAY(`datetime`)
```

The trick here is to use [`LAST_DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) to figure out in which month each observation occurs. It takes any date, datetime, or timestamp item and figures out the date of the last day of its month.  This query gives you a result set containing one temp per month, for the highest temp in the month. Try it. Make sure it works for you.

Next, you should join that to your detailed observation table, like so:

```
 SELECT w.*
   FROM weatherdata w
   JOIN (
              SELECT MAX(temp) temp, LAST_DAY(`datetime`) month_ending
                FROM weatherdata
               GROUP BY LAST_DAY(`datetime`)
        ) m   ON w.temp = m.temp
             AND LAST_DAY(w.`datetime`) = m.month_ending
  ORDER BY w.`datetime`
```

This will give you the detailed observations. Notice that if the highest temperature occurred on more than one observation in any given month, you'll get them all.

Finally, if you only want some months, put this WHERE clause right before the ORDER BY clause

```
   WHERE `datetime` >= '2016-04-01 
     AND `datetime` <  '2016-05-01  -- to get April 2016
```

Pro tip: don't use names of datatypes, like `datetime`, as column names. It makes it hard to troubeshoot your database.

Comment: Thanks Ollie. That is way more SQL than I understand, I will save it and come back to it when I'm more into SQL.

Comment: Ohh, I forget, can you point me to some reading that can help me understand your example? I may be able to get it running but I prefer understanding instead of just copy/paste-leaving it :) I can see that I need to dive into the grouping and joing, and? I not only wants the max/min for the month but also for each separate day and year. Kind Regards

Comment: Queries with `GROUP BY` are known as *aggregate* queries.  `JOIN` functions are just what they say they are. You can look those things up. I tried to break down my answer so you can get the hang of the aggregate query first, then the join operation. Codecademy and Khan Academy have SQL tutorials. Friends don't recommend W3Schools to friends, though.  It's **great** that you're trying to understand rather than just use an SO answer as a magic spell.

Comment: Thanks Ollie. I know Codecademy, and I took the PHP-tutorial some time ago and it was great. I will also take their SQL. Have nice day Ollie.